# data extraction using sqoop from Teradata

Tags: hadoop, teradata, sqoop

I've been trying a sqoop import on a 2TB table from Teradata DB to Hive. It's full table import I'm trying of. The query generated in background is very simple select:

```
SELECT A, B, C FROM TABLE WHERE (A>=0) AND (A<100000);
```

The range is decided based on min, max values of a column and the number of mappers I provide in the sqoop query of course.

The question might not be very sqoop specific but because it is used in the activity, I'm tagging it as well here. It's the spool space in Teradata DB that gets full and reaches upto a shocking 8 TB. The table hardly is 2 TB, while the spool occupied reaches 8.

I'm really not sure what goes on in the Teradata DB background that the spool shoots up this high. Does anybody has any idea on what's actually going on in the background and any workaround on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your actual `sqoop` command?

Comment: Spool space issue is caused due to teradata user spool limit set.It has nothing to do with sqoop, also If you could try the same with TPT extract you could confirm whether its the teradata user specific spool causing the failure.